# Edit Classes in Featured Product - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, class, woocommerce

In WooCommerce I need to change the way the featured products widget is being showed. 
The class that controls this is `\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\classes\widgets\class-wc-widget-featured-products.php` but if i change it i will lose my changes in the next upgrade. This is not a template and i already tried to copy into my theme folder but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plugin for that  check it here http://docs.woothemes.com/document/create-a-plugin/ in this plugin you copy and edit your features product widget